# How do Handlebars custom Helper arguments work

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I am trying to understand how the arguments of the [Handlebars helpers](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/block-helpers.html#conditionals) come to be.

I understand the actual functions that are called, but not how the parameters they need are given to them.

**Example 1 - built in Helper:**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("if", function(conditional, options) {
  if (conditional) {
    return options.fn(this);
  } else {
    return options.inverse(this);
  }
});
```

Is called via

```
{{#if blockExists}}
   //blalba
{{/if}}
```

What are `conditional` and `options` and how are they actually parsed to the function?

**Example 2 - Custom Helper:**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('concat', (str1, str2, separator) => {
  return `${str1 || ''}${separator || ''}${str2 || ''}`;
});
```

How is this Helper even called? How are the parameters parsed? How to use the return value, due to it not being `true` or `false`?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Documentation: [Helpers with Multiple Parameters](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#helpers)

Your hbs file:

```
{{concat "str1" "str2" "separetor"}}
```

The first parameter is the name of the helpers the others are the arguments

Your Helpers:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('concat', (str1, str2, separator) => {
 return `${str1 || ''}${separator || ''}${str2 || ''}`;
});
```

the values returned by the {{expression}} could be a string and you should pass it with `return new Handlebars.SafeString(result);`

Comment: Why is there no `#` necessary before the concat, like it is at the `#if`? Also what where do `conditional` and `options` in the if clause come from?

Comment: `Options` is a handlebar provided options object, `#` is for `build-in` helpers

Comment: Small Correction: `#` is not used for built-in helpers but for conditioning code segments -> code conditioning need the `#` in `{{#helper x z}}`  _conditioned code_ `{{/helper}}` if helper is true